# CXF Client in Spring with Basic / NTLM Authentication sent on every request

Tags: java, spring, authentication, client, cxf

we connect to a WebService through `Apache CXF` and `Spring`.
Now, at a first glance, `Basic / NTLM Authentication` works as expected.
Though I noticed that the Authorization Headers are sent on each and every request that is done.

The question is, how can I get the CXF Client to only send the Authorization Headers on the first request?

Please note that `SESSION_MAINTAIN_PROPERTY` is already set to true, so session cookies are saved and sent on the request...

many thanks in advance!

Comment: Ok, right now i implemented an Interceptor to throw away the Authorization-Header if cookies are sent with the request, since then i know that we are already authenticated. But this cant be the actual solution, i guess there must be some property to set in CXF for that behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, right now i implemented an Interceptor to throw away the Authorization-Header if cookies are sent with the request, since then i know that we are already authenticated.